# How to make hover action icons to be clickable in Jquery?

Tags: jquery, css

I tried to make action icons appear on each hover item and clickable to perform specific event on it. Yet, from my script below I could not prevent action icons from disappearing, that's why I could not click on any icon to perform specific action.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var ul = `
       <div class="item">
     <ul class="list-inline" style="float: left;margin-left: -110px;margin-top: 20px;">
       <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-plus-circle icon-add"></i></a></li>
       <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o icon-edit"></i></a></li>
       <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-trash-o icon-remove"></i></a></li>
       <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-arrows-v icon-move"></i></a></li>
     </ul>
       </div>
  `;
  $('.item').hover(
    function() {
      $(ul).insertBefore($(this).find('.item-head'));
    },
    function() {
      $(this).find('div.item').remove();
    });

})
```

```css
.item-head {
  color: #365efe;
}

.action-icon {
  float: left;
  margin-top: 25px;
  margin-left: -40px;
}

.icon-add {
  color: #4caf50;
}

.icon-edit {
  color: #00bcd4;
}

.icon-remove {
  color: #f44336;
}

.icon-move {
  color: #9e9e9e;
}

.in-item {
  display: block;
}

.out-item {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-T8Gy5hrqNKT+hzMclPo118YTQO6cYprQmhrYwIiQ/3axmI1hQomh7Ud2hPOy8SP1" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="col-sm-12">
  <div class="message"></div>
  <h3>Preview</h3>
  <div class="container" style="border: 1px solid #ccc;width: 70%;">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12">
        <div class="item">
          <h3 class="item-head" style="float: left;">Customer [form]</h3>
          <p style="clear: both;">Customer is module for recording information related to customer such as Name, Address, Date of Birth, Place of Birth, ID Number, etc.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <h3 class="item-head">First Name English [label]</h3>
          <p class="definition">The name that was given to you when you were born and that comes before your family name. This field accept only English Character.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <h3 class="item-head">Salutation [label]</h3>
          <p>A greeting in words or actions, or the words used at the beginning of a letter or speech. This field has values such as Mr, Ms, Miss.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Although, I try to set `Timeout()` to delay it time disappearing, it still does work.

```
        setTimeout(function(){
                $(this).find('div.item').remove();
            },4000);
```

As shown, how can I be able to make an action icons be clickable? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Added the below css to your existing code to hold the list on hover.

```
.list-inline {
float: left;
background: trasparent;
position: absolute;
left: -110px;
top:12px;
height:40px;}

div.item { position:relative; }
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var ul = `
       <div class="item">
     <ul class="list-inline">
       <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-plus-circle icon-add"></i></a></li>
       <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o icon-edit"></i></a></li>
       <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-trash-o icon-remove"></i></a></li>
       <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-arrows-v icon-move"></i></a></li>
     </ul>
       </div>
  `;
  $('.item').hover(
    function() {
      $(ul).insertBefore($(this).find('.item-head'));
    },
    function() {
      $(this).find('div.item').remove();
    });
})
```

```css
.item-head {
  color: #365efe;
}

.action-icon {
  float: left;
  margin-top: 25px;
  margin-left: -40px;
}

.icon-add {
  color: #4caf50;
}

.icon-edit {
  color: #00bcd4;
}

.icon-remove {
  color: #f44336;
}

.icon-move {
  color: #9e9e9e;
}

.in-item {
  display: block;
}

.out-item {
  display: none;
}

.list-inline > li:last-child {
padding-right: 25px;
}
.list-inline {
    float: left;
    background: trasparent;
    position: absolute;
    left: -110px;
    top:12px;
    height:40px;
}
div.item {
position:relative;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-T8Gy5hrqNKT+hzMclPo118YTQO6cYprQmhrYwIiQ/3axmI1hQomh7Ud2hPOy8SP1" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="col-sm-12">
  <div class="message"></div>
  <h3>Preview</h3>
  <div class="container" style="border: 1px solid #ccc;width: 70%;">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12">
        <div class="item">
          <h3 class="item-head" style="float: left;">Customer [form]</h3>
          <p style="clear: both;">Customer is module for recording information related to customer such as Name, Address, Date of Birth, Place of Birth, ID Number, etc.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <h3 class="item-head">First Name English [label]</h3>
          <p class="definition">The name that was given to you when you were born and that comes before your family name. This field accept only English Character.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <h3 class="item-head">Salutation [label]</h3>
          <p>A greeting in words or actions, or the words used at the beginning of a letter or speech. This field has values such as Mr, Ms, Miss.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: @Ram_UL, thanks very much, it's just working, however, I could not attach any event handler to an icon, ex, ```$('.icon-add').on('click',function(){
   alert('add');
  });```. Thanks.

Comment: hi, I could do it by this `$('body').on('click','.icon-add',function(){
   alert('add');
  });`. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1):

Use it in this way:

```
 function() {
    setTimeout(() => {
     $(this).find('div.item').remove();
    },2000)
    })
```